# Share functionality between two classes

Tags: c#, polymorphism, c#-6.0

This question sounds very common, but I have no idea how i should implement it.

My scenario:

[image]

## **Question**: How to implement `DirectionTile`?

Behavior implementation of `DirectionTile`:

```
abstract class DirectionTile
{
    public Point Direction;

    public Tile Next => Board.GetTile(Coords + Direction);
}
```

As you can see property `Coords` will be from the base class (?), which is `Tile`.

Both `RailTile` and `SailTile` are `DirectionTiles`. However, I can not just inherit from `DirectionTile`, as `SailTile` needs to inherit from `WaterTile` and this would case 2 relations with `Tile` (really want to use polymorphism like this).

I hope somebody can help me with this problem, that I can not solve. Let me know if my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: Given C# has no multiple inheritance, use "traits", or the next best option: extension methods.

Comment: Strategy pattern might make sense. Your execute() method might just be a "getNextTile()" operation.

Comment: You should take a look at [Component based game engine](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/). Basically, it emphasis that using tradidtional OOP inheritance can cause architecture issue, like yours. Instead, each "object" in the game can be a aggregation of components, allowing multiples combinations of components without common roots.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, DirectionTile is a behaviour implemented by entity.

Use simply an Interface IDirectionTile, and to prevent multiple implementation you could provide an extension Methods :

```
public interface IDirectionTile
{

}

public static class TileExtensions
{
    public static void GetDirection(this IDirectionTile th)
    {

    }

    public static void Next(this IDirectionTile th)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if I could it implement it like this, but it still requires me to access `Tile` properties from the `Next()` method, which isn't possible like this. It would require ugly castings between `Tile` and `IDirection`.

Comment: Those properties are in public ? If so, then create an interface with the property you need and no need to cast

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this: 
 Base from your diagram Tile will be your base/parent class and all other classes will be its child class. which then will inherit the property and function(s) that the Tile has.
 For DirectionTile i think it's a separate entity/class where you will just instantiate WaterTile and RailTile

```
public abstract class Tile
{
    private Point direction;

    public Point Direction
    {
      get { return direction; }
      set { direction = value; }
    }

    public abstract string someFunction();
}
```

Now to inherit the property and the function:

```
public class WaterTile : Tile
{
  //all property and functions now are accessible from the Tile base class
  private string somevariable;
  public string Somevariable
   { 
   get{return somevariable;} 
   set{somevariable=value;}
   }
  public override string someFunction()
  {
       //return "something";
  }
}

public class SailTile : WaterTile
    { //if there are additional properties/functions in your WaterTile it will be accessible by this class (SailTile) but not to other class
       //in this case Somevariable is accessible in this class
    }
```

Comment: Read the big letters in my post again :)